# Цикл for each Idea 2016.3.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, foreach, сниппет

[image: for each Idea 2016]

Почему Idea создает шаблон цикла с одной половиной аргумента на первой строке и второй - на второй. Не имею опыта работа в других IDE, объясните, пожалуйста.

PS в <kbd>Code Style</kbd> <kbd>Java</kbd> <kbd>Wrapping and Braces</kbd> галка <kbd>New line after '('</kbd> в цикле "for" не стоит.

Comment: А почему там двоеточие?

Comment: потому, что двоеточие - это неизменяемая часть аргумента, в отличии от параметров, если вы не троллите, конечно

Comment: Хм.. Я ожидал `for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)` :)

Comment: @Qwerty Это `foreach`, а не `for`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перейдите в `File->Settings->Editor->Live Templates->Android->foreach` и снимите галочку с `Reformat according to style`.

[image: settings]

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решенипе помогло. Не могли бы вы рассказать, почему по умолчанию стоит именно вариант с разрывом строки, это действительно удобно для профессиональной работы, или сложилось исторически?

Comment: @coolsv ИМХО это нужно для того, что бы у Вас не было длинной колбасы в `for`, которую невозможно прочитать. Лично у меня такие ситуации встречаются крайне редко, в следствии чего мне удобней когда `foreach` в одной строке. Кстати если Вы замечали, в редакторе справа есть вертикальная линия - она показывает рекомендуемую ширину кода, для того, что бы код был более читабелен. Если строка вылазит далеко за неё,  то лучше, конечно, разбить её на несколько строк.